# Reporting Services chart text is blurry when zooming in

Tags: reporting-services

The text within the Reporting Services Graph is rendered as an image, rather than rendering again when zooming in.  As the text in tables/matrix' do.

How do I force it to render properly and not blur the text when I zoom in?